# Fragment is not overlapping buttons that are in the activity

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments

I made a `progress-bar fragment`; the goal is to show it whenever the buttons in my `MainActivity` are clicked. However, I encountered this dilemma (using Android 5.1):

https://gyazo.com/8632f6e50cdce599847258939cc4f109

Any ideas what's the deal here? I can't pin-point the problem. The only solution is to hide the button when clicked. It works but I interpret is as badly-written code.

**Main Activity**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final Button bRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bRegister);
    final Button bTest = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bTest);
    bTest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.activity_register, progressFragment);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    });
```

**ProressFragment**

```
public class ProgressFragment extends Fragment {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_progress, container, false);
        ProgressBar pb = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        return view;
    }
}
```

**XML for MainActivity** (Looks like this:https://gyazo.com/8ecef7ada74cf92730b4d99757383da7)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_register"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="googleplayservices.samples.android.teamtreehouse.com.kibbleuserc.RegisterActivity">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Password"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/etPassword"
        android:layout_below="@+id/etEmail"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/etEmail"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/etEmail"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Phone Number"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/etPhoneNum"
        android:layout_below="@+id/etPassword"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/etPassword"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/etPassword"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Name"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/etName"
        android:layout_below="@+id/etPhoneNum"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/etPhoneNum"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/etPhoneNum"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Email"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/etEmail"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/etEmail"
        android:id="@+id/tvEmailError"
        android:layout_above="@+id/etPassword"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/etEmail"
        android:textColor="#FFFF4444"/>

    <TextView
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tvPasswordError"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/etPassword"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/etPassword"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/etPassword"
        android:layout_below="@+id/etEmail"
        android:textColor="#FFFF4444"/>

    <TextView
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/etPhoneNum"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/etPhoneNum"
        android:id="@+id/tvPhoneNumError"
        android:layout_below="@+id/etPassword"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:textColor="#FFFF4444"/>

    <TextView
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/etName"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/etName"
        android:id="@+id/tvNameError"
        android:layout_below="@+id/etPhoneNum"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:textColor="#FFFF4444"/>

    <Button
        android:text="Register"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/bRegister"
        android:layout_below="@+id/etName"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="86dp"/>

    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bRegister"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="31dp"
        android:id="@+id/bTest"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

**XML for ProgressFragment (Looks like this:https://gyazo.com/93bbb11af8cb8a0df8d4d6cf97b84ef1)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light">

    <ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: try replace fragment instead of add .

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work

Comment: Did you try setting the _height_ and _width_ of the _relative layout_ in _fragment_progress_ to _fill_parent_?

The explicit marginTop on the two buttons might have something to do with this.

Comment: Yes I did. I also tried to remove margintop, but it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens because the two buttons have an elevation that is not 0 while your `RelativeLayout` in your `Fragment` have an elevation of 0.

You can fix it wrapping the `RelativeLayout` of the `Activity` in a `FrameLayout`, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_register"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="googleplayservices.samples.android.teamtreehouse.com.kibbleuserc.RegisterActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!-- Add all the views that you have inserted in your RelativeLayout -->

    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

However the optimized solution is to set the elevation in your `Fragment`'s root `View` with `ViewCompat.setElevation(View,int)` but you have to know the right elevation to set to bring the `View` on top of the others. In this case you won't need the `FrameLayout` wrapper and the `onDraw()` and `onLayout()` calls will be optimized.

Comment: Thanks, does frame layout make the elevation of everything the same? and why is the `button's` elevation not 0 (is this by default?)?

Comment: @MatthewFrancis The FrameLayout, in this case, is only useful to add a container. The elevation of the button is not 0 because the default StateListAnimator of the button is: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/res/anim/button_state_list_anim_material.xml

Comment: Thanks for everything!